# Show in designer control names in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

It's possible to show with maybe a key combination all the control names in the design view of a windows forms application?

Some key that makes visible the control names or some extension?

Comment: Unclear what feature you are looking for with this request.  Consider using `View - Other Windows - Document Outline` to see all of the control names in their container hierarchy.

Comment: I mean a feature that with a key pressed the control names appear over each control. Is this feature exists?

Comment: I've never heard of such a feature.  Maybe someone wrote a plug-in to do that.  It's probably a code smell that you have too many controls in your design.

Comment: Yah.. i have too many controls.. the code is not mine and the controls are named label10, label21, etc..